# SQL Server 2008 ReadOnly Role for Production Machine

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, readonly, production, role

I am a programmer temporarily tasked with the duties of a DBA at our firm.
I need to create a User Id(or a role) that will have read-only access to EVERYTHING on the production SQL Server 2008.

This user should have read-only access to all DBs on this machine.
That includes being able to view data, schema, scripts, stored procedures, functions, table design, linked servers, SQL Server Agent jobs, User IDs , Logins etc.

In short, **EVERYTHING**

However, it should NOT be able to MODIFY OR CREATE any of these.

I have managed to achieve most, but am unable to get read-only access to Linked servers, SQL Server Agent jobs, User IDs , Logins.

Is there any role(s) that will give me **read-only** access to **EVERYTHING** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the ability to view all logins.

`GRANT VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO <Read-Only-User-Who-Sees-Everything>`

Managed to get the ability to view all jobs on SQL Server Agent:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'SQLAgentReaderRole', '<ReadOnly-User-Who-Sees-Everything>'
```

Managed to get ability to view properties of Linked Server. Well the properties window is still blank, but the following SQL statements do the trick for now.

```
select * from sys.linked_logins 
select * from sys.servers
```

Comment: SqlAgentReaderRole actually grants create permissions, per http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/2009/01/22/read-only-access-to-sql-server-jobs/

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is not quite correct - adding that role grants modify permissions, despite the name.  This blog post covers how you can actually accomplish this task, at least with regards to jobs:

http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/01/21/creating-a-real-sqlagentreaderrole/